# How to create solr core (collection) using solr Rest API?

Tags: apache, solr

i am new in solr and try to using solr in our nodejs project.

There is multiple databases in our nodejs project(mongodb database) and each database has "products" collection. I want to use solr for searching on Server.

I want to create a new core (collection) with name "databasename_products" for each database to store their products data in solr. For every change in products document, i want to update data in solr core (collection).

How can i create new core (collection) in solr using solr REST API ? 
Is there is better approach to fulfill our requirement ?

Answer (score 1):

Please find the link which give all the details of it

[create core](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/CoreAdmin+API#CoreAdminAPI-CREATE)

I have the same approach for my project, where in I have created a separate core for each project/workspace.

All the updated of the respective project/workspace happen to the same workspace .

I have created the core with project/workspace name.

Search query fired from a workspace goes to the specific core and not all.

In my view creating a seperate core is sort of having indexes to your data.

This improves the performance as it has to search in a perticular chuck or within one specified core.

Comment: i am trying to create core by using link url, but it is giving me error. Can you please share your email id so that i could clear some doubts.

Comment: you can post the error here ...If I could not solve ...other experts may help you on the same...Anyway you can see my if in my profile..:)

Comment: i am using standalone solr. then what will be value of instanceDir, config, schema and dataDir in core create action? which are required parameters in it ?

Comment: how can we copy all the required directores (like config, lang) to the new core directory??
becuase when we just hit to the above CREATE action, then it just ask to copy all the required directories first in which we will have our solrconfig.xml

Comment: @user3029929 : You need not have copy for the new core? your configset will have all these files...While creating core you need to mention the configset used for it...the same configuration will be applied to the core

Comment: @Abhijit Bashetti : i tried the same but coundt make it.

http://localhost:8984/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=solrnameTemp&instanceDir=configsets/basic_configs&config=solrconfig.xml

Comment: Its should be like "http://localhost:8984/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=solrnameTemp&instanceDir=configsets/basic_configs&configSet=basic_configs"

Comment: I dont know which version you are using...but you can create your folder of configset and use the same